# Sum of Datediff with same date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to sum up the date differences and everything is fine except that i want to add 1 if there are same dates , say for example if the from date is : 01/01/2003
and to date is 01/01/2003 then i want to add 1 day, but its not adding 1 day , instead it only adds a day if it is 01/01/03 to 01/02/2003. This is to calculate leave, and it should calculate 1 day if someone has applied leave for one day i.e 01/01/2003 to 01/01/2003

```html
 $sql = "SELECT l.id as typeid,l.*,ud.firstname, ud.lastname,ud.email,l.leave_starting_from,l.leave_partial_from,ud.joining_date, l.typename, l.no_of_leave_days,(CASE SUM(datediff(STR_TO_DATE(lr.to_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(lr.from_date, '%m/%d/%Y'))) when NULL then '0' else SUM(datediff(STR_TO_DATE(lr.to_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(lr.from_date, '%m/%d/%Y'))) end) as days_in_betw,  lr.from_date, lr.to_date FROM pr_users u INNER JOIN pr_users_details ud on ud.userid= u.id LEFT OUTER JOIN pr_leave_type l ON ((FIND_IN_SET( u.departmentid , l.function ) >0) AND (FIND_IN_SET( ud.designation_id , l.level ) >0) and (l.gender='All' or l.gender=ud.gender)) LEFT OUTER JOIN pr_leave_request lr ON u.id = lr.userid and lr.sr_type = l.id";
```

Particularly the else part

```html
SUM(datediff(STR_TO_DATE(lr.to_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(lr.from_date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: got any solution or still fight with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same, May this function will solve your problem.

```
function days_calculation($start_date,$end_date){
  $start = new DateTime($start_date);
  $end = new DateTime($end_date);
  // otherwise the  end date is excluded (bug?)
  $end->modify('+1 day');

  $interval = $end->diff($start);

  // total days
  $days = $interval->days;

  // create an iterateable period of date (P1D equates to 1 day)
  $period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

  // best stored as array, so you can add more than one
  $holidays = array();

  foreach($period as $dt) {
      $curr = $dt->format('D');

      // substract if Saturday or Sunday
      if ($curr == 'Sat' || $curr == 'Sun') {
          $days--;
      }

      // (optional) for the updated question
      elseif (in_array($dt->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
          $days--;
      }
  }

  if($days==1){
      $days = $days." day";
  } else {
      $days = $days." days";

  }

  return $days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. It is in T-SQL so might require some rejigging.

```
/* Setting up your problem */
create table #temp
(
personID int,
from_date datetime,
to_date datetime
)

insert into #temp values (1,'01/01/2003','01/01/2003')
insert into #temp values (1,'01/01/2013','05/01/2013')
insert into #temp values (2,'01/01/2013','05/01/2013')


/* Here the nested statement calculates the number of days off, then the outer select group this per personID */
select  personID
    ,   SUM(DaysOff) as TotalDaysOff
from    (
        select  personID
            ,   datediff(day, lr.from_date, lr.to_date)+1 as DaysOff
        from    #temp lr
        ) lr
group by personID
```

You need to change this to MySQL and then put it in the select statement you have.

Comment: Please give someone an answer in the language they asked for, if you choose to give someone an answer for sql and say make this sql you should give him both solutions